# can we have more than one module.exports statements in one js file

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am newbie to javascript.I am  developing mobile apps using Titanium studio.
My question is regarding javascript which is as follows.

I have one file js file named commonUi.js in this file I am defining common UI components which I can use in different windows.

Now I am defining two object function inside commonUi.js which are as follows.

```
function component1(){

}

function component2(){

}
```

Now My core question is can I write following two statements inside my commonUi.js file

1. module.exports = component1;
2. module.exports = component2;

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only have one `module.exports =` in your module, but you can do something like this to achieve what you want:

```
var CommonUi = function() {

    var component1 = function() {

    }

    var component2 = function() {

    }

    return {
        component1: component1
       ,component2: component2
    }
}();

module.exports = CommonUi;
```

And then you can just use it like this: `commonUi.component1();`

Comment: You mean to say we can not use more than module.export statements in one javascript file.

Comment: @Android_Crazy exactly. 1 JS file is 1 module. You can of course use 10 files for 10 modules.